# Logging fewer entries into Yii console.log

Tags: mysql, yii, deadlock

I have a `Yii` application with many concurrent console jobs writing to one database.  Due to the high concurrency sometimes I get MySQL deadlock errors.  Sometimes these can be too many.  The `console.log` file becomes too big, and it translates to more expenses.

I want to prevent logging of specific `CDbException` instances, or at least suppress them altogether (I am handling the exceptions and can generate more compact log sentences from there).

`YII__DEBUG` is already commented out.

Can anyone please help me figure out how to do this?

Thanks a lot!!

Regards.

Comment: how are you logging? what class are you using for this?

Comment: Thanks for the response Harikrishnan.  It is the CDbCommand.php that is logging failures, and it includes the failed SQL in it (search for "The SQL statement..." in yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to modify the log statement in yii/framwework/db/CDbCommand.php that was logging the failed SQL.  I converted it into a trace statement:

Yii::trace(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand::{method}() failed: {error}. The SQL statement executed was: {sql}.', array('{method}'=>$method, '{error}'=>$message, '{sql}'=>$this->getText().$par)),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'system.db.CDbCommand');

I am anyway catching the exception and logging a more compact version of the sentence, so it is OK for me to do it.

This was the easiest way I could find.  We don't upgrade Yii very often, so if and when we go to the next version I'll probably repeat the change.